# How not to close the console output with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, console

I have a console program that prints out some data to the stdio. The problem is that when I click the program in explorer. The console pops up, and gone as soon as it prints out the data.

How can I set the console program so that it is not closed after the process is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a shortcut to cmd.exe.
Then go into properties and change the target to something like

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C"yourprogname & PAUSE"

eg

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C"c:\windows\system32\IPCONFIG & PAUSE"

Answer (score 0):

One simple method would be to wrap the console program in a small batch file with pause on the end.
eg
sample.bat would list a directory and wait for you to press a button.

```
DIR
PAUSE
```

Another option if you simply want to read the text would be to add | clip to the end to redirect the text to the clipboard so you can use it as you want.

eg

```
DIR | clip
```

will send a directory listing to the clipboard.